# What's the subtitute for direct_to_template in django 1.5. This is giving errors

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

def post_tweet(request, tweet_id=None):

    tweet = None
    if tweet_id:
        tweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet, id=tweet_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TweetForm(request.POST, instance=tweet)
        if form.is_valid():
           new_tweet = form.save(commit=False)
           new_tweet.state = 'pending'
           new_tweet.save()
           send_review_email()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/thankyou/')
   else:
     form = TweetForm(instance=tweet)
   return direct_to_template(request,'post_tweet.html',{'form': form})

   urls.py

   urlpatterns = patterns('',
         url(r'^$', 'post_tweet'),
```

Answer (score 1):

The function based generic views were replaced by the class based views starting in Django 1.3. The replacement for `direct_to_template` would be [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview). Or you could just switch it to use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut which has the same signature.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

...
def post_tweet(request, tweet_id=None):
...
    return render(request,'post_tweet.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: What change did you make? Are you trying to use `TemplateView` or `render`?